# Could coq derive this solution automatically? Can coq manipulate algebraic expressions when performing the search for a proof?

Tags: coq, symbolic-math

This problem is taken from a Corporate Finance course, but the financial details aren't what matters.

The problem was that given this formula:

[image]

and values for:

[image],

one had obtain **r_wacc**. (I'm simplifying the problem a little)

The solution was to divide the numerator and denominator of each fraction by **E** to obtain:

[image]

Which equals to:

[image]

Now obtaining **r_wacc** is easily done by substituing with the known values.

Could coq derive the solutions automatically given only the initial formula and the same known values? Or in other words, can coq manipulate algebraic expressions when performing the search for a proof?

Comment: Bare-bones Coq "can't", but perhaps some coq library that uses reflection and computational definitions.  It is a bit lika asking "Can Java compute the solution of X?".

Comment: While there will certainly be those that do that (now or in the future), you would rather use Coq to prove that that particular solution is actually _correct_.  Some other program would search and find a solution, and produce a proof or proof obligation that gets sent  off to some i.e. SMT solver, which produces a proof that is checked by Coq.  The neat thing is that the SMT solver can be fast and buggy, Coq checks because the proof.